# Heroku Automated Generated Name

Tags: heroku

How to change heroku automated created name (ex: glacial-dawn-22102 ) its not related to my project name!

When I input the command git push heroku main then it creates the name of the file. Is there any opton to modify this?

```
git push heroku main
```

Comment: The automated names are randomly generated. They aren't _supposed_ to be related to your project name. What are you trying to do: generate a new random name, or rename your app to something specific?

Comment: Yes. I want to rename it.